# Incorrectly formatted html inconsistencies between DOM and what's displayed in firefox plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, html-parsing

I'm currently developing a firefox plugin. This plugin has to handle very crappy website that is really incorrectly formatted. I cannot modify these websites, so I have to handle them.

I reduced the bug I'm facing to a short sample of html (if this appellation is appropriate for an horror like this) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title.</title>
    <!-- Oh yes ! -->
    <div style="visability:hidden;">
        <a href="//example.com"> </a>
    </div>

<!-- If meta are reduced, then the bug disapears ! -->
<meta name="description" content="Homepage of Company.com, Company's corporate Web site" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Company, Company & Co., Inc., blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

</head>
<body class="homePage">

<div class="globalWrapper"><a href="/page.html">My gorgeous link !</a></div>

</body>

</html>
```

When opening the webpage, « My gorgeous link ! » if displayed and clickable. However, when I'm exploring the DOM with Javascript into my plugin, everything behaves (DOM exploration and innerHTML property) like the code was this one :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title.</title>
    <!-- Oh yes ! -->
    </head><body><div style="visability:hidden;">
        <a href="//example.com"> </a>
    </div>

<!-- If meta are reduced, then the bug disapears ! -->
<meta name="description" content="Homepage of Company.com, Company's corporate Web site">
<meta name="keywords" content="Company, Company &amp; Co., Inc., blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla, blablabla">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US">
</body>
</html>
```

So, when exploring the DOM within the plugin, the document is somehow fixed by firefox. But this fixed DOM is inconsistent with what is in the webpage. Thus, my plugin doesn't behave as expected.

I'm really puzzled with that issue. The problem exists in both firefox 3.6 and firefox 4 (didn't tested firefox 5 yet). For example, reducing the meta, will fix the issue.

Where does this discrepancy come from ? How can I handle it ?

EDIT: With the answer I get, I think I should be a little more precise. I do know what firefow is doing when modifying the webpage in the second code snippet. The problem is the following one : « In the fixed DOM that I get into my plugin, the gorgeous link doesn't appear anywhere, but this link is actually visible on the webpage, and works. So the DOM I'm manipulating, and the DOM in the webpage are different - they are fixed in a different manner. » . So where does the difference come in the fixing behaviour, and how can I handle that, or, in other terms, how can I be aware, in my plugin, of the existance of the gorgeous link ?

NB: Exploring the DOM with firebug show a different DOM from what I'm getting in my module. Both DOM are fixed by firefox, but in a different manner. I do get the DOM like this :

```
 var html = browser.contentDocument.documentElement;
 // Then, for example :
 html.getElementsByTagName('a'); // Returns only the a element in the header. On the webpage, only the a in the body appears.
```

DOM exploration with firebug show that the div and a within the header are removed, which is a different behaviour.

EDIT² : The code in my plugin is ran after the page loading end, by this mecanism :

```
gBrowser.addTabsProgressListener({
    onStateChange: function(aBrowser, aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
        if( (aStateFlags & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP) ) {
            // Some operations including the DOM parsing here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh gosh. I hope you're charging a good fee for this kind of abuse?

Comment: Yeah, the original webpage is terrible. The worst is that the develloper put his name almost everywhere in the code within comments. As if he were proud of it . . . I really like the doctype, which is really decorative :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue and failed - everything seemed to work fine in Firefox 5. My mental powers tell me that you are trying to access the document before it finished loading. That's why you need a lengthy meta tag, the document body downloads in two network packets then and you are looking at the document when only the first packet has been received. Wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event before accessing the document. Or, if you are using a progress listener, wait for `onStateChanged` call with `STATE_STOP` and `STATE_IS_DOCUMENT` flags set.

Comment: I did add the mecanism I used to ensure that the page is fully loaded before processing it. Did you see a problem with it ? However, interesting direction to look in ! If you don't have the issue, can you share the code snippet you used when trying ? I did load way bigger source file in this plugin successfully, so if it has something to do with loading, it must be something more subtle ;)

Comment: Ok, did test with a setTimeout arounf my code, and got the right result. So this is, indeed, related to when I parse the DOM. Thank you for pinting me the direction !

Comment: Got it ! Due to Document malformation (or a firefox bug ?) the event is triggered 2 times, one with the worng DOM, one with the right one. Even if it was more subtle than what you gave me, it send me in theright direction. Thank you SO MUCH :D

Answer (score 0):

> Where does this discrepancy come from ?

The start and end tags for the `<head>` and `<body>` elements are optional in HTML 4.

While inside the `<head>`, if something is encountered that must appear in the `<body>`, the `<head>` is automatically terminated and the `<body>` started.

`</head><body>` are then ignored as errors.

> How can I handle it ?

That rather depends on what you actually want to achieve. The DOM you get is the DOM you get though, so that is what you have to work with.

Comment: Yes, I do understand what you explain here. But that's not what the question is about. Obviously, the html code is incorrect, and fixed by firefox as you explain. But the problem is, that this is different between what I get in my plugin (where gorgeous link is removed du to incorrectness), and what is displayed on the webpage (where gorgeous link isn't removed at all). So the DOM I get and the DOM used to display the webpage are different. This is my problem. Where does this difference come from and how can I get the original webpage.